# why do I not need to reload to pick up my change from 'kittens' to 'puppies' in chrome extensions getting started?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

while going through http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html I actually did not have to reload my extensions page to pick up my changes from 'kittens' to puppies, how is that so?

Comment: I think that particular section of the docs are just out of date for popups or were mistakenly copied from a background script guide.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you open the popup, `popup.html` is loaded and rendered anew (including any accompaning JS scripts or code).